# How can i make params `out` in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I find myself in the situation requiring this

```
public static void Fill(this SomeClass c, params out object[] p)
```

and calling it as

```
c.Fill(out i, out i2, out sz, out i3, out sz2);
```

However i get the error `error CS1611: The params parameter cannot be declared as ref or out`

How can i pass in variable length arguments and make them writeable? All of these are a mixture of ints and strings

Comment: How many arguments do you typically have?

Comment: What about creating 1 to n overloads? If you need to have so many arguments, think about encapsulating them into a structure instead, or a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have an answer to your question; Consider the following code snippet, with the main "InvokeMemberMethod" function doing the job you ask for. I encountered the same problem as you and came up with this solution:

Note: the "isOutXX" parameter specifies if the preceeding parameter is an "out" parameter.

```
static object InvokeMemberMethod(object currentObject, string methodName, int argCount, 
        ref object arg1, bool isOut1,
        ref object arg2, bool isOut2,
        ref object arg3, bool isOut3,
        ref object arg4, bool isOut4,
        ref object arg5, bool isOut5,
        ref object arg6, bool isOut6)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(methodName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("methodName");
        }

        if (currentObject == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("currentObject");
        }

        Type[] argTypes = null;
        object[] args = null;
        if (argCount > 0)
        {
            argTypes = new Type[argCount];
            args = new object[argCount];

            argTypes[0] = arg1.GetType();
            if (isOut1)
            {
                argTypes[0] = arg1.GetType().MakeByRefType();
            }
            args[0] = arg1;

            if (argCount == 2)
            {
                argTypes[1] = arg2.GetType();
                if (isOut2)
                {
                    argTypes[1] = arg2.GetType().MakeByRefType();
                }
                args[1] = arg2;
            }

            if (argCount == 3)
            {
                argTypes[2] = arg3.GetType();
                if (isOut3)
                {
                    argTypes[2] = arg3.GetType().MakeByRefType();
                }
                args[2] = arg3;
            }

            if (argCount == 4)
            {
                argTypes[3] = arg4.GetType();
                if (isOut4)
                {
                    argTypes[3] = arg4.GetType().MakeByRefType();
                }
                args[3] = arg4;
            }

            if (argCount == 5)
            {
                argTypes[4] = arg5.GetType();
                if (isOut5)
                {
                    argTypes[4] = arg5.GetType().MakeByRefType();
                }
                args[4] = arg5;
            }

            if (argCount == 6)
            {
                argTypes[5] = arg6.GetType();
                if (isOut6)
                {
                    argTypes[5] = arg6.GetType().MakeByRefType();
                }
                args[5] = arg6;
            }
        }

        MethodInfo methodInfo = currentObject.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, argTypes);
        int retryCount = 0;
        object ret = null;
        bool success = false;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                //if (methodInfo is MethodInfo)
                {
                    Type targetType = currentObject.GetType();
                    ParameterInfo[] info = methodInfo.GetParameters();
                    ParameterModifier[] modifier = new ParameterModifier[] { new ParameterModifier(info.Length) };
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (ParameterInfo paramInfo in info)
                    {
                        if (paramInfo.IsOut)
                        {
                            modifier[0][i] = true;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    ret = targetType.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, currentObject, args,
                        modifier, null, null);
                    //ret = ((MethodInfo)methodInfo).Invoke(currentObject, args,);
                    success = true;
                }
                //else
                {
                    // log error
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {

            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            retryCount++;
        } while (!success && retryCount <= 1);

        if (argCount > 0)
        {
            if (isOut1)
            {
                arg1 = args[0];
            }

            if (argCount == 2)
            {
                if (isOut2)
                {
                    arg2 = args[1];
                }
            }

            if (argCount == 3)
            {
                if (isOut3)
                {
                    arg3 = args[2];
                }
            }

            if (argCount == 4)
            {
                if (isOut4)
                {
                    arg4 = args[3];
                }
            }

            if (argCount == 5)
            {
                if (isOut5)
                {
                    arg5 = args[4];
                }
            }

            if (argCount == 6)
            {
                if (isOut6)
                {
                    arg6 = args[5];
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;

    }




    public int OutTest(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public int OutTest(int x, out int y)
    {
        y = x + 1;
        return x+2;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object x = 1, y = 0, z = 0;
        Program p =  new Program();
        InvokeMemberMethod(p, "OutTest", 2, 
            ref x, false, 
            ref y, true, 
            ref z, false,
            ref z, false,
            ref z, false,
            ref z, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 20):

You can't have it treat the arguments as `out` (or `ref`) **and** make use of the `params` feature at the same time. It simply doesn't work. The best you can do is to create an array parameter, make the **array** `out`, declare an array variable and call the method passing the array, then inspect each element manually by index.

```
Foo(out object[] data) {...}
object[] result;
Foo(out result);
// look at result[0], result[1], result[2] etc
```

So: you **cannot do** what you want. Even if you could, `ref` / `out` **never** work unless there is an *exact* match between data type, so it would *still* have to be:

```
object o1, o2, o3, o4;
Foo(out o1, out o2, out o3, out o4);
// cast o1, o2, o3, o4
```

Which still isn't what you want.

Comment: Additionally, you could define several overloads that take successively more out parameters, up to a point. For example, 5 overloads with 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 out parameters, respectively. That should cover many if not most use cases, and then for the catch-all case where the caller needs a *lot* of outs, use the whole-array method described here.

Answer (score 7):

There is no technical need for `out` here. This works:

```
void Fill(object[] p)
{
    p[0] = 1;
    p[1] = 42;
    p[2] = "Hello";
    p[3] = -1;
    p[4] = "World";
}

object[] p = new object[5];
foo.Fill(p);
i = (int)p[0];
i2 = (int)p[1];
sz = (string)p[2];
i3 = (int)p[3];
sz2 = (string)p[4];
```

---

You could return your values as [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(VS.100).aspx):
*(define your own tuple class if you're not using .NET4.0)*

```
static Tuple<int, string> Fill()
{
    return new Tuple(42, "Hello World");
}
```

and then define extension methods to unpack tuples:

```
public static class TupleExtensions
{
    public static void Unpack<T1, T2>(
        this Tuple<T1, T2> tuple,
        out T1 item1,
        out T2 item2)
    {
        item1 = tuple.Item1;
        item2 = tuple.Item2;
    }
}
```

Then you can write this:

```
int i;
string sz;

foo.Fill().Unpack(out i, out sz);
```

Comment: Thats the problem. The point was to not do this and be lazy like calling a simple function instead of horrible one line typecast or function calls per statement :(

Comment: close but how would i unpack a variable length turple?

Comment: Tuples are, by definition, not of variable length.

Comment: It's a pity there is not the syntatical sugar for params out. Assume you want to write a function that rounds some float numbers to nearest integer. Writing `Utils.Round( out x, out y, out size, out height);` is much better than `x = Math.Round(x);` or creating your own array

Comment: I would argue since the function changes the array, you should at least make it `ref` just to indicate the design purpose of the array. Also since in the _op_ question the arguments are defined locally outside the function, the `ref` keywords carries the same meaning over.

Answer (score 2):

1) If you can avoid the need to get the values in declared variables, then passing the array and populating it is the best option, as shown by dtb's answer.

2) Otherwise you can have a simple wrapper for your variable.

```
public class Wrapper //or may be generic?
{
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public Wrapper(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Now you can call

```
var i = new Wrapper(0), i2 = new Wrapper(0), i3 = new Wrapper(0);
c.Fill(i, i2, i3);
i.Value //your value here

public static void Fill(this SomeClass c, params Wrapper[] p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
    {
        p[i].Value = 1; //assigning
    }
}
```

You will have to deal with `Value` property after calling `Fill` method.

3) You can make use of closure. Something like the `Ref<T>` class implemented as shown:

```
public static class Ref
{
    public static Ref<T>[] Create<T>(params Expression<Func<T>>[] getters)
    {
        return getters.Select(Create).ToArray();
    }

    public static Ref<T> Create<T>(Expression<Func<T>> getter)
    {
        return new Ref<T>(getter);
    }
}

public sealed class Ref<T>
{
    readonly Func<T> getter;
    readonly Action<T> setter;

    public Ref(Expression<Func<T>> getter)
    {
        var output = getter.Body;
        var input = Expression.Parameter(output.Type); //or hardcode typeof(T)
        var assign = Expression.Assign(output, input);
        var setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(assign, input);

        this.getter = getter.Compile();
        this.setter = setter.Compile();
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return getter(); }
        set { setter(value); }
    }
}

public static void Fill(this SomeClass c, params Ref<object>[] p)
//assign inside

object i = 0, i2 = 0, i3 = 0;
c.Fill(Ref.Create(() => i, () => i2, () => i3));
//i, i2 etc changed
```

---

Few things to note:

1. All the above approaches are basically `ref` approaches, compiler doesn't simply force assigning value of parameters inside the method before the control leaves as in the case of `out` which is your question, but as far as I know `out` is not possible here.
2. I like the first one, simple, and *conventional*. If not possible my vote is for 3rd approach.
3. As others have talked about, you can only pass the exact same type as `ref/out` parameters. So if your method by definition takes arbitrary references of `object` type, you have to declare even your variables as `object` locally. In the last approach, you can make the whole thing generic like by changing parameter type to `Ref<T>` from `Ref<object>` but that means your all local variables should also be one `T`.
4. You can use a dictionary structure to cache `Ref<T>` to avoid recompiling same trees.
5. The same implementation can be used to pass properties and variables as method arguments or return values by reference.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can't use `params` and `out` together. You have to construct an array at the call site.

This is because `params` tells the compiler to do the same thing - construct an array from the specified arguments. Unfortunately, when the compiler creates the array, you don't get a reference to it; even if the variable is written with a new array, you can never get to it.

I would guess you are [asking for a thin metal ruler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/a-parable). What problem are you trying to solve with this mechanism?

Comment: I hate when people ask for a thin metal ruler. I'm parsing text via user input. I dont know how much data i can extract and which the user wants to ignore thus i am allowing the user to pass in variable length params (and a type to say ignore this entry) which should be set to the value in the class or data pass through. Thus i want to do exactly what i asked. I can return an array but in practice i have variables that already exist and its easier to do it the way i asked.

Comment: Fair enough. Since it has been established that the syntax isn't supported, can you write a type which manages this for you? By which I mean, if you could have any syntax that doesn't involve the C# team, what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an array by ref.

Edit:

This would of course change your calling method:

```
object[] array = new object[] { i, i2, sz, i3, sz2 };
c.Fill(ref array);
```

Comment: put all in one basket and send this new one!!

Comment: problem here is array will change but i1, i2 etc wont. Copying the value back to the variable defaults the purpose of the lazy method i would like.

Comment: Have you tried it? 

All array types are implicitly derived from System.Array, which itself is derived from System.Object. This means that all arrays are always reference types which are allocated on the managed heap, and your app's variable contains a reference to the array and not the array itself.

Comment: @Gnoome: if `Fill` sets `array[0]` to 42 then `i` will *not* receive the value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't imagine the original questioner needs this answer 11 years later, but I found this old question when searching for an overlapping requirement... and thinking through the answer to this question made me realise why my related one wouldn't work very neatly.

For this question, it was implied that the caller needs to communicate the number of parameters and their types to the `Fill(...)` function - how else does it match up the types to the calling site?

The intended syntax at the calling site could be achieved like this:

```
public class SomeClass { }

public static void Fill(this SomeClass c, Type[] outputTypes, out object[] p)
{
  p = new object[outputTypes.Length];
  // TODO: implementation to fill array with values of the corresponding types.
}

// this overload can be removed if "fill" of an empty array is meaningless.
public static void Fill(this SomeClass c)
{
  c.Fill(new Type[0], out _);
}

public static void Fill<T>(this SomeClass c, out T r1)
{
  c.Fill(new[] { typeof(T) }, out var p);
  r1 = (T)p[0];
}

public static void Fill<T1, T2>(this SomeClass c, out T1 r1, out T2 r2)
{
  c.Fill(new[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2) }, out var p);
  r1 = (T1)p[0];
  r2 = (T2)p[1];
}

// ... extend as required depending on maximum number of out parameters that might be needed
// in particular the 5-parameter version is included in this sample to make OP's sample code line work.

public static void Fill<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(this SomeClass c, out T1 r1, out T2 r2, out T3 r3, out T4 r4, out T5 r5)
{
  c.Fill(new[] { typeof(T1), typeof(T2), typeof(T3), typeof(T4), typeof(T5) }, out var p);
  r1 = (T1)p[0];
  r2 = (T2)p[1];
  r3 = (T3)p[2];
  r4 = (T4)p[3];
  r5 = (T5)p[4];
}

public static void someFunction()
{
  SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
  int i, i2, i3;
  string sz, sz2;
  // the line below is exactly as shown in question.
  c.Fill(out i, out i2, out sz, out i3, out sz2);
}
```