# C# Array of out params

Tags: c#, parameters, out

I have tried to decrease the complexity of an customized ORM, therefore I'm trying to do something like this:

Mi problem is that I need to implement an out params Model[] variable

something like this,

`public bool GetEntities(params out Model[] models)`

or

`public bool GetEntities(out params Model[] models)`

However it looks like my syntax is not valid for the compiler, Do you have ideas to solve the problem to returns an undetermined number of objects as out params without implements an IEnumerable such as arrays, lists, dictionaries... to be a little bit faster at the runtime?

The follow block clearly allows you to see the problem.

```
public class Model
{
}

public class Entity1 : Model
{
}

public class Entity2 : Model
{
}

public class EntityN : Model
{
}

public class FooDBContext
{
    private IDictionary<string,object> rows;
    public void SetSQLRecord(IDictionary<string,object> row)
    { 
     // This function sets a local dictionary that will be used to perform the multicast.
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> HasNext()
    {
      // this returns the current row returned by the query
        yield return null;
    }
    
    public bool TryExecuteSQL(string SQL )
    {
        //execute
        return true;
    }
    
    public void SetValues(params Model[] models)
    {
        
    }
    
    public bool GetEntities(params out Model[] models)
    {
    
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new FooDBContext();
        string SQL = "Select Entity1.* , Entity1.* , Entity2.* , EntityN.* , Entity2.* FROM Entity1,  Entity1,  Entity2,  EntityN,  Entity2 where (expression)";
        a.TryExecuteSQL(SQL);
        foreach(var row in a.HasNext())
        {
            a.GetEntities(out Entity1 e1_1,  out Entity1  e1_2,  out Entity2  e2_1,  out EntityN en_1 , out Entity2 e2_2 );
            a.GetEntities(out e1_1,  out e1_2);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that to my knowledge. However you could use array object with out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912326/how-can-i-make-params-out-in-c#:~:text=You%20can't%20have%20it,each%20element%20manually%20by%20index.

Comment: `I need to implement an out params Model[] variable` Why do you *think* you need to do that?

Comment: In the same way that you can use a params string[] args to suppor this a = Method(a,b,c,...,z) I need an undetermined list of out params

Comment: I dont like return the instans of an array, else pointer to more than une instances to use them directly as variables.

Comment: This sentence says all GetEntities(out Entity1 e1_1,  out Entity1  e1_2,  out Entity2  e2_1,  out EntityN en_1 , out Entity2 e2_2 ); "out Entity1 e1_1"  It means instance a new instance as out param

Comment: `I dont like return the instans of an array, else pointer to more than une instances to use them directly as variables.` Returning an array _will already_ return a pointer (well, a reference - but basically a pointer).

Comment: you are right, when You return an array of pointers that must be accessed using an index accessor(lst-prfrm), after this, you have to perform a cast to the object, the idea is to avoid the calling of several casting instructions(lst-prfrm) else access to undetermined instances of undetermined types directly taking the advantage of the compiler, part of the code will be complemented by the compiler to win performance.  (lst-prfrm) => lost performance.

Comment: The answer to "should I write an ORM?" is almost always "No". Why not use Dapper?

Comment: ADO is very good (faster but, a little bit obsolete), Dapper has a  normal performance, But it has an academic proposal. I hope in the implementation create for each Type a dynamic (run time) function that "directly" maps the entities and uses a IL cached thread safe function for this... Finally, I used up all my ideas when checking the C#9 syntax; out params clausules are not supported.

Comment: `But it has an academic proposal` I have literally no idea what this sentence means.

Comment: If you are really worried about performance you likely shouldn't be using `IDictionary` (instead use `Dictionary` or `ConcurrentDictionary`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do what you want to do. Rather add a collection to the argument and set that as the output param. I suggest doing something like this:

```
public bool GetEntities(out IList<Model[]> outputModel, params Model[] models)
{
   //method logic here
   //some assignment to argument outputModel
   // eg. outputModel.Add(//)
   // return true or false
}
```

Comment: This is a workaround, but I can not execute some actions like this: method( out ClassA variable a , out ClassA variable b ,) to instance them in the same instruction

Comment: As you can see here: GetEntities(out Entity1 e1_1,  out Entity1  e1_2,  out Entity2  e2_1,  out EntityN en_1 , out Entity2 e2_2 );  You are instancing the variable that will the method  internally instance,